# How can ı remove character from string in c

Tags: c, string, c-strings

Can anyone please help me.I want to remove character from `char*` in C.

For example, `char *str` this str equals to "apple" and first i remove 1. character and define a new variable then remove 2. character and define new variable and so on until the str ends.

How can ı do that ? I'm completely new to C, and just can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Consider using `strdup` to create new strings copied from str+1, str+2, ..., str + strlen(str) - 1.

Comment: Can you provide expected input and expected output? Have you tried anything to achieve those?

Comment: If you want to remove from the left, you don't really need to remove: simply start 1 char to the right... `printf("%s\n", "apple"); printf("%s\n", "apple" + 1); printf("%s\n", "apple" + 2); printf("%s\n", "apple" + 3);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you only need to remove characters from the left.

Because strings in C are arrays of characters, and arrays are pointers to the first element of the array, you can create variables that point to specific indices in you original char array.

For example

```
char* myString = "apple";
char* subString = myString+1;

printf("%s\n%s\n", myString, substring);
```

would produce the output

```
apple
pple
```

We could generalize this to store all substrings obtained by removing characters from the left in an array of `char*` pointers (pointers to pointers). Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** GetSubStrings(char* input)
{
    int length = strlen(input);
    char** result = calloc(length, sizeof(char*));
    
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = input + i;
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char* myString = "apple";
    
    char** subStrings = GetSubStrings(myString);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(myString); i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", subStrings[i]);
    }
    
    free(subStrings);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are *not* pointers to the first element. But by convention we typically pass arrays around by using pointers to the first element.

Comment: This code is unnecessarily complex and potentially gives the OP the impression that multiple substrings have been allocated and hence are safe to manipulate independently. A far simpler solution such as `printf("%s\n", myString + i)` in your main for loop would work identically, with absolutely no need for GetSubStrings at all.